# Change insert line color with VBA macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

Code below was created (not by me, and saved as *.dotm) in Microsoft Word 97-2003, when default "insert shape/line" was black. Used as procedure template with specific cover page, header, outline style, etc. When the *.doc files are saved to *.docx, and the "`SignoffLine`" macro is activated, the inserted line's color is blue (MS Word 2010 default for Insert Shape/Line?).

I can change the default color per document, and I can change it via `Normal.dotm`, but want to edit the macro below so inserted line is always black.

```
Sub SignoffLine()
    On Error GoTo endthis
    i = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    Set oFFline = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine(554, i + 12, 524, i + 12).Line

    With oFFline.Line
        .Weight = 0.75
    End With
        oFFline.Name = "hline" & idi
        idi = idi + 1
    endthis:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple... You need to define `oFFline` object as a `Shape` and then to set its properties as follow:

```
Sub SignoffLine()
    Dim oFFline As Shape
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo endthis

    i = Selection.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
    Set oFFline = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddLine(554, i + 12, 524, i + 12)

    With oFFline.Line
        .Weight = 0.75
        'set black color 
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End With
    oFFline.Name = "hline" & idi
    idi = idi + 1

    endthis:
    Set oFFline = Nothing
End Sub
```

For further information, please see: [Shape Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196943.aspx) and [RGB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1dyw8b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks! 
I had tried this line of code in the same spot: 
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
but without Dim within the sub. Searching original code, I found the shapes, text, etc., called at the beginning of the